# Grammar of nounの多さに

Tags: grammar, particle-に, i-adjectives, na-adjectives

> 品揃え**の多さに**ついつい買いこんでしまい、...
>   I ended up unintentionally buying ??? complete set...

I'm struggling to understand the part in bold. I know that 多い is 'many', and that you can convert adjectives to nouns by changing the last い to さ.
So I get 多さ = 'manyness' (obviously not a real word) maybe 'multitude' or 'multiple'??

Now I have a 'multiple of complete sets' with a に on the end. I can't make any further sense of it.

I also wondered if when you add a さ the thing you make is a na-adjective rather than a noun so I could make an adverb from 多さに but that didn't help either.

I also notice there's no object marker を.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 品揃え ≒ *assortment/lineup* of goods (Probably you can't use *complete set* here...)
- I think *abundance* is the closest noun to 多さ ≒ 豊富さ. 品揃えの多さ ≒ 品揃えの豊富さ means "the largeness of the selection of goods" or simply "the large selection of goods" in this context.
- 買い込む doesn't necessarily take an object. 買い込む by itself can mean "to do a lot of shopping".
- This に is a particle which can sometimes mark a cause/reason. (eg, そのニュースに驚いた, その言葉に嬉しくなった) In this case you can understand it as "*because of* (the  abundance)" or "*due to* (the abundance)".