# Why was the に particle used in くすぐったさに思わず本を取り落としてしまいそうになった?

Tags: particle-に

> くすぐったさに思わず本を取り落としてしまいそうになった。

As far as I am concerned に cannot turn a normal noun into an adverb unless it is an adjectival noun, so I guess this is the target particle に. In here I see they have normalized 擽ったい with さ, but what is the target particle に doing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grammar of nounの多さに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/grammar-of-noun%e3%81%ae%e5%a4%9a%e3%81%95%e3%81%ab) Also:  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83466/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72042/5010 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83880/5010