# What does 「に」 mean at the end of the 「侘しさに」?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

The full sentence is 「寄る辺ない侘しさに」. I did some research and found out that「に」is used with na-adjectives to basically turn them into adverbs, but「侘しい」is an i-adjective, so it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: But then 侘しさ is a noun derived from 侘しい, right?

Comment: @jogloran right

Comment: So in that case に is operating on a noun, not any kind of adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, is this really a **full** sentence? I googled and found [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg09lNupc1s). If your phrase is from this, 寄る辺ない侘しさに is a **part** of a sentence, not a full sentence. Please always [provide the entire context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010).

This に is a cause/reason marker that is used with a word related to emotion or psychological reactions.

- [に in コントロールに苦しまなくなった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72042/5010)
- [When do you use に to indicate a cause or reason for something?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95996/5010)
- [Grammar of nounの多さに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36949/5010)
- [Meaning of に in この狭さに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83466/5010)

侘しい is an i-adjective, but note that it has already been nominalized with さ ("-ness") here. 侘しさ is a noun meaning "loneliness" or  "melancholy".

> 寄る辺ない侘しさに頬杖ついてるようじゃ変わらない
>
> (literally) If it's like you rest your cheek in your hand because of desolation with nowhere to turn, things won't change.
> → When you feel desolate with nowhere to turn, just resting your cheek in your hand won't change anything.

Even if your 寄る辺ない侘しさに is not from this song, に is still a cause/reason marker. If this is a book title, the implicit focus is how someone psychologically reacts to the 侘しさ, so it might be translated like "Loneliness Makes Me..." or "In Desolate Solitude...".

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [comments](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/102375/what-does-%E3%81%AB-mean-at-the-end-of-the-%E4%BE%98%E3%81%97%E3%81%95%E3%81%AB#comment167135_102375), に is operating on a noun, in this case it means Because of / From. The sentence is incomplete.